# What are the differences in the ordering of properties in a Datastore index?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I was experimenting with datastore indexes, and I noticed that I can order the properties in an index multiple ways:

```
IsItemActive ▲ + Rating ▲
- or -
Rating ▲ + IsItemActive ▲
```

What is the difference between the two indexes above? One allows me to query `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Rating > 3 AND IsItemActive = FALSE` but the other does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datastore relies very heavily on the ordering of index properties in order to enforce its rule that every query must scale with the size of the result set.

In order to answer a query, all the results for that query **must** appear sequentially in the index.

So, consider the two indexes:

Index(IsItemActive, Rating)

```
Item(Rating=3, IsItemActive=False)   <----
Item(Rating=4, IsItemActive=False)   <----
Item(Rating=3, IsItemActive=True)
Item(Rating=4, IsItemActive=True)
Item(Rating=5, IsItemActive=True)
```

Index(Rating, IsItemActive)

```
Item(Rating=3, IsItemActive=False)   <----
Item(Rating=3, IsItemActive=True)
Item(Rating=4, IsItemActive=False)   <----
Item(Rating=4, IsItemActive=True)
Item(Rating=5, IsItemActive=True)
```

In order for your query `SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Rating > 3 AND IsItemActive = FALSE` to have all results next to each other, it must use the `Index(IsItemActive, Rating)` index. The other index does not have all the results you need next to each other.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection) is an article about how index selection works. Also, I would highly recommend the [Google I/O talk (2008)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) on how Datastore works under the covers.